# Problema con porcentaje automatico JavaScript, Html y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Que tal amigos tengo el siguiente problema, estoy batallando para mostrar el porcentaje **automáticamente** de las siguientes 2 cantidades **Las cantidades es la suma de otros campos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente si me pongo en el campo **Total2** borro un digito o doy en las flechas del teclado me aparece ya el porcentaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego el codigo de los totales y del campo porcentaje asi como del JavaScript que estoy utilizando para hacer dicha operacion, esos 3 campos no los guardo ni en la base de datos solo son para que el usuario los visualice

```
<label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Total1</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular();" name="importe" required title="Completar campo" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo ($row["Enero"]+$row["Febrero"]+$row["Marzo"]+$row["Abril"]+$row["Mayo"]+$row["Junio"]+$row["Julio"]+$row["Agosto"]+$row["Septiembre"]+$row["Octubre"]+$row["Noviembre"]+$row["Diciembre"]); ?>"></div>


<label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Total2</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular()"  name="cuota" required title="Completar campo" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo ($row["Rem1"]+$row["Rem2"]+$row["Rem3"]+$row["Rem4"]+$row["Rem5"]+$row["Rem6"]+$row["Rem7"]+$row["Rem8"]+$row["Rem9"]+$row["Rem10"]+$row["Rem11"]+$row["Rem12"]); ?>"></div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">% Siniestralidad</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <input type="text" id="total-input" name="" class="form-control m-b">
                                            <span id="total" type="text" name=""></span>
                                        </div>
```

Aqui esta el Script el cual utilizo para que me calcule el porcentaje **Total2 * 100 / Total1**

```
<script>
        function formatear(dato) {
            return dato.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
                return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
            });
        }
        function calcular(){
            var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
            var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;
            var porce = parseInt(valor2)*100/valor;
            $("#total-input").val(formatear(porce.toFixed(2)))
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes llamar a la funcion `calcular()` para que aparezca el valor al cargar la pagina asi:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Total1</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular();" name="importe" required title="Completar campo" class="form-control m-b" value="500"></div>


<label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Total2</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular()"  name="cuota" required title="Completar campo" class="form-control m-b" value="600"></div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">% Siniestralidad</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <input type="text" id="total-input" name="" class="form-control m-b">
                                            <span id="total" type="text" name=""></span>
                                        </div>


<script>
        function formatear(dato) {
            return dato.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
                return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
            });
        }
        function calcular(){
            var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
            var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;
            var porce = parseInt(valor2)*100/valor;
            $("#total-input").val(formatear(porce.toFixed(2)))
        }
        calcular();
    </script>
```

Comment: Genial me funciono